# CSS Two Column Layout Not Working

Tags: css, html, layout, web

My code is suppose to make a two-column layout, the header at the top, footer at the bottom, navigation at the left column in between the top and bottom, and finally the main at the right column. The problem is that the main is overlapping with the navigation column.

Here is the CSS for my file:

```
body        {   background-color: #000033;
                background-image: url(primehorizontal.png);
                color: #003300;
                font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                margin-left:180px;
                padding: 0px 20px 180px 0px;}

header      {   background-repeat: no-repeat;
                height: 100px; }

h1          {   white-space: nowrap;
                overflow: hidden;}

h2          {   color: #003366; }

h3          {   padding-top: 10px;
                color: #006600; }

nav         {   float: left;
                width: 150px;
                font-weight: bold;
                font-size: 1.2em; }

nav a       {   text-decoration: none;
                text-align: center;
                color: #FFFFCC;
                font-weight: bold;
                border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
                padding: 5px; }

nav a:link  {   background-color: #003366; }
nav a:visited{  background-color: #48751A; }
nav a:hover {   border: 3px inset #333333; }

nav ul      {   list-style-type:none;
                margin: 0;
                padding-left: 0; }

dd          {   font-style: italic;
                font-size: .90em;
                height: 200%; }

.contact    {   font-weight: bold;
                font-size: .90em;
                font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif; }

.floatleft  {   float: left;
            padding: 0 20px 20px 0; }

.clear      {   clear:left; }

footer      {   font-size: .60em;
                clear:both;
                margin-left: 180px;}

img         {   border-style:none; }

#wrapper    {   background-color:#FFFFCC;
                min-width: 700px;
                max-width: 960px;
                padding: 0px 0px 20px 30px;
                border: 1px ridge blue;
                width: 80%;
                margin-right: auto;
                margin-left: auto;
                box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;}

header, nav, main, footer {display:block;}
```

Here is one of my html5 files:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="prime.css"/>
    <title>Prime Properties :: Financing</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="wrapper">

<header>
    <h1><img src="primelogo.gif" width="650" height="100" alt="Prime Logo"></h1>
</header>

<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="listings.html">Listings</a></li>
        <li><a href="financing.html">Financing</a></li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>
    <h2>Financing</h2>
    <p>We work with many area mortgage and finance companies.</p>
    <h3>Morgages FAQs</h3>
    <dl>
        <dt>What amount of morgage do I qualify for?</dt>
            <dd>The total basic monthly housing cost is normally based on 29% to 41%   of your gross monthly income<dd>
        <dt>Which percentage is most often used?</dt>
            <dd>The perecentage used depends on the lending institution and type of financing.</dd>
        <dt>How do I get started?</dt>
            <dd>Contact us today to help you arrange financing for your home</dd>
    </dl>
</main>

<footer>
Copyright &copy; 2014 Prime Properties<br>
<a href="mailto:123@123.com">Paul Clef Ube</a>
</footer>
```

Comment: It would help to use jsfiddle.net.

Comment: Never heard of it before. I'll try it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the issue worked out. Just played around with your code a bit, thought you may find it useful.

Though `calc()` is tempting, it's not necessarily the best choice due to compat issues.

[image: Styles]

```
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body {   
  background-color: #000033;
  background-image: url(primehorizontal.png);
  color: #003300;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  background: #003366 url(https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/156843/worldmap.png) no-repeat center 35%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-left: -21px;
  margin-right: -21px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 24px;
  bottom: 0;
  right: auto;
  margin: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 140px;
  height: 65px;
}

h1 { 
  padding-left: 55px; 
  font-size: 25px; 
  line-height: 100px; 
  color: white; 
}


h2 { 
  margin-bottom: 5px; color: #003366; 
}

h3 {
  margin: 2px 0px 6px;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #006600; 
}

nav {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  width: 150px;
  font-size: 1.2em; }

nav a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FFFFCC;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: 3px outset #CCCCCC;
  padding: 5px; 
  margin: 2px 0; 
}

nav a:link  {
   background-color: #003366; 
}
nav a:visited { 
  background-color: #48751A;
}
nav a:hover { 
  border: 3px inset #333333; 
}

nav ul { 
  list-style-type:none;
}
dt {

}
dd {   
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 4px 0 10px 18px;
  line-height: 1.2;
  font-style: italic;
  font-size: .90em;
  height: 200%;
}
dt:first-child {
  margin-top: 15px;
}
.contact { 
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: .90em;
  font-family: "Times New Roman", sans-serif; 
}

.floatleft  {
  float: left;
  padding: 0 20px 20px 0; 
}

.clear { 
  clear:left; 
}

footer {
  font-size: .60em;
  width: 100%;
  clear: both; 
}

img {
   border-style: none;
}

#wrapper {  
  background-color: #FFFFCC;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 700px;
  max-width: 960px;
  padding: 30px 20px 15px;
  border: 1px ridge blue;
  margin: auto;
  box-shadow: inset -3px -3px 3px 3px #00332B;
}

main {
  padding: 20px 0px 20px 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 77%;
}
```

Comment: Wow thank you so much. That's exactly how I want it to look like, I mean the layout.

Answer (score 1):

add this:

```
main{
    float:left;
    width:calc(100% - 150px);
}
```

I have added the new width (you might want to add a fallback) so the main always fit with your fixed sized nav (plus the padding on the wrapper)

Comment: I'll try it but I want my navigation to be on the left column and the main on the right column.

Comment: float:left doesn't mean it will be on the right... it will be floating left to the previous element that is floating left (if it can fit). Since the nav is floating left, the main will be floating on its right.

Comment: Ooooh it does make it clean, making the main go below the navigation column. But, I want the navigation to have it's own column by itself without anything at the bottom of it. I hope you understand.

Comment: I'll check it out, but I think that did the trick. Thanks! I'll give you the answer checkmark once it's ready in 3mins.

Answer (score 0):

I see you have a class "floatleft", but you never assign it to anything.
Try giving your elements locations.  For instance if you wanted something to float left tell it how from from the left it should go.  In your CSS you may trying something like this in .floatleft{ float: left; left: 10px}.  .floatright{ float: right; right: 10px;}.

Comment: hmmm I was gonna assign the floatleft class to a picture later on. Your comment is noted though. Thanks!